# JavaScript join between objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have JSON object that has some values, and from those values, I need to generate a name, basically, I need to add '/' between those values.
So my object looks like this

```
"options":[
            {
               "value":"Red",
               "key":"Color"
            },
            {
               "value":"L",
               "key":"Size"
            }
         ]
```

And for this specific case I did it like this:

```
title: `${combination[0].value}/${combination[1].value}`
```

And the output looks like `Red/L`, and this is correct. But what If I have more or less objects?

What would be the easiest way to make this work?